# Tried to modify a stack in a function by passing by pointer, printing top element shows different results inside and outside the function

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Basically, I coded a function to modify the stack initialized in the main function. I passed the pointer to the stack in the function parameter to achieve this. However, I found some issues.
Printing the top element of the stack inside and outside of the function shows different results. In fact, printing it outside does not work at all. It just gives some random characters.

I'm using VS 2019 in the Windows environment.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stack>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void func(stack<char*> *messages) {
    char yes[] = "what are you doing?";
    messages->push(yes);
    cout << "In func: " << messages->top() << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    stack<char*> messageStack;
    func(&messageStack);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    cout << "Out func: " << messageStack.top() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and here is the console output

```
In func: what are you doing?
Out func: w@
```

Comment: When not forcing the console to use UTF8 encoding, the output is following `In func: what are you doing?
Out func: 7T→`♀÷û`

Answer (score 1):

You have issue printing string in main because you keep a pointer to array of chars `yes` which is local to function `func` and when `func` terminates that array is destroyed and your stack keeps dangling pointer. One of the solution is to change your stack to:

```
stack<const char*> messageStack;
```

then you can keep pointers to string literals which are constants and not destroyed:

```
void func(stack<const char*> *messages) {
    const char *yes = "what are you doing?";
    messages->push(yes);
    // or directly
    messages->push( "I am programming" );
    cout << "In func: " << messages->top() << endl;
}
```

but you better use `std::string` or `std::string_view` to avoid such problems.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your solution using the const modifier except I used the brackets [] for `yes` array. And it still outputs random characters. I wonder what is the issue here.

Comment: Yes it would not work, because changing type to `const char *` is not the solution, it just allows to store pointer to string literal and allows to remove `[]`. So you just changing type to `const char *` but keeping local array does not make any sense